Setting ttl for a blob corrupts the blob in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2
I am trying to set ttl (time to live) for a file in Azure Data Lake Gen2 with hierarchical namespaces so that I can remove it automatically.
I am doing this
const setBlobTtlDays = async (containerName, blobPath, blobTtl) => {
    const blobUrl = await getFullBlobUrlWithToken(containerName, blobPath); // contains SAS token
    await axios.put(blobUrl, {}, {
        headers: {
            'x-ms-expiry-option': 'RelativeToNow',
            'x-ms-expiry-time': `${blobTtl}`,
            'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
        }
    });
}

It does set ttl for a file, but it also CORRUPTS THE FILE so that it has 0 or 2 bytes.

The correct code would be:
const setBlobTtlDays = async (containerName, blobPath, blobTtl) => {
    const blobUrl = await getFullBlobUrlWithToken(containerName, blobPath); // contains SAS token
    await axios.put(`${blobUrl}&comp=expiry`, {}, { // I forgot comp=expiry
        headers: {
            'x-ms-expiry-option': 'RelativeToNow',
            'x-ms-expiry-time': `${blobTtl}`,
            'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
        }
    });
}

I forgot to add &comp=expiry to the query.
